# How to pass Any to a generic method?

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, generic-collections

I have a class that encloses and flatten a generic class (in order to contain a list of different generic typed instances):

```
trait XFun [P,V] {
  def apply(args: P): V
}

class XRoute (val handler: XFun[_,_])

class XRoutes (val routes: List[XRoute])
```

so that when I create XRoutes, it can contain a list of XFun with different generic types:

```
val routes = new XRoutes (List[XRoute](new XRoute(new XFun[Int,Int] {
  def apply[Int,Int](args: Int) = 0
}), new XRoute(new XFun[String, String] {
  def apply[String, String](args: String) = ""
}
))
```

However when I try to call it, it causes issue:

```
def parse(str: String) : Any = {/* impl */}

val inputObj = parse(inputString)
val outputObj = routes(1).handler.apply(inputObj)
```

This gives error on the apply line:

```
Type mismatch, expected: _$1, actual: Any
```

Currently my only solution is to create a reflected methods from `MethodSymbol` and call using `reflectedMethod`, but how do I achieve this without reflection?

Note that I do not want to change `XFun` to `apply(Any):Any` because I wanna type enforcement on the front end (e.g. when creating XRoute object, I want to do `XFun[String,String]` instead of having to do `XFun[Any,Any]`).

Comment: `Any` is generally symptom there is something wrong before, especially when working with generic/type safe code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think your trait definition has too many types and should just be:

```
trait XFun [P,V] {
  def apply(args: P): V
}
```

And then you can just cast the object using `asInstanceOf`:

```
routes(1).handler.asInstanceOf[XFun[Any,Any]].apply(inputObj)
```

Note that this is not type safe and will fail at runtime if you pass the wrong type of argument to an `XFun`.